# Same screen is rendering twice or three time in stacknavigation in react-navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Same screen rendering twice as shown in screen shot. How can solve this issue?

#### same screen multiple time

[image: same screen multiple time]
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",

```
import Login from "../components/login/";
import Signup from "../components/signup/";

HomeDrawerRouter.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: null
});

const screens = {
  Login: { screen: Login, path: 'Login/:messageScreen', navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false, header: null
    }   },
  Signup: { screen: Signup, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false, header: null
    } }}

let MainStackRouter = StackNavigator(screens,
{
  initialRouteName: index
})

const navigateOnce = getStateForAction => (action, state) => {
  const { type, routeName } = action
  return state &&
    type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE &&
    routeName === state.routes[state.routes.length - 1].routeName
    ? null
    : getStateForAction(action, state)
}
MainStackRouter.router.getStateForAction = navigateOnce(
  MainStackRouter.router.getStateForAction
)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?